# Bubble sorting numbers prob

Tags: python

I am trying an algorithm for a bubble sort and there is a part I don't understand

```
 nums = [1,4,3,2,10,6,8,5]

 for i in range (len(nums)-1,0,-1):

     for j in range(i):

         if nums[j] > nums[j+1]:
             temp = nums[j]
             nums[j] = nums[j+1]
             nums[j+1] = temp

             print(nums)
```

what does the numbers (-1,0,-1) mean in this part of the code (it dosent sort properly without it) v v v

```
for i in range (len(nums)-1,0,-1):
```

Comment: What specifically about it are you asking about? Did you look up the documentation of `range` to see what argument to it is for?

Comment: i was trying to loop it according to the length of the nums list, but it didnt work properly so someone told me to add the numbers after the len(nums) and now it works. I dont get what its for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey:
first one is starting point, second tells python where to stop, last one is step.

len(nums) - it gives you (durms..) length of this list, in our case it's 8,
len(nums)-1 - it's 8-1, we are doing this because when going through list python will start on number 0 and end at number 7(still 8 elements, but last one has index 7 not 8),
We will stop at 0, with step -1. So iteration will look like:

```
num[len(nums)-1] = num[7]
num[len(nums)-1-1] = num[6]
num[len(nums)-1-1-1] = num[5]
.....
num[len(nums)-1-1-1-1-1-1-1] = num[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax for `range` in python is -

```
range(start, end, step)
```

In your case, the looping is essentially starting from the last element(Index n-1) & moving towards the first element(Index 0) one step at a time.

Comment: so it is looping backwards?

Comment: Yes, it's looping backwards, starting from the last element & moving towards the first, one step at a time.

Comment: Thanks, but why does it work when looping backwards but not forwards? Arnt, they meant to be the same?

Comment: Please, check this explanation of [Bubble sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/).  It provides a detailed explanation.